# How to iterate dates while reading in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, time-series

I have a large data set, which consists in 20 years of data, with a lot of information. I can only take a maximum of 8 months each time and insert into a new data frame. For the moment, I have it hard coded. However, I need to make it automatic, without losing information and it should read until the current datetime.

So, for example I have:

```
import pandas as ps
import datetime
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange

df__2000_2000 = initial_dataset.read_data(start=ps.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 100000), end=ps.datetime(2000, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 100000), limit=-1)
df__2000_2001 = initial_dataset.read_data(start=ps.datetime(2000, 9, 1, 0, 1, 2, 100000), end=ps.datetime(2001, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 100000), limit=-1)
df__2001_2001 = initial_dataset.read_data(start=ps.datetime(2001, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 100000), end=ps.datetime(2001, 12, 10, 0, 1, 1, 100000), limit=-1)
df__2001_2002 = initial_dataset.read_data(start=ps.datetime(2001,12, 10, 0, 1, 2, 100000), end=ps.datetime(2002, 8, 10, 0, 1, 1, 100000), limit=-1)
df__2002_2003 = initial_dataset.read_data(start=ps.datetime(2002, 8, 10, 0, 1, 2, 100000), end=ps.datetime(2003, 3, 10, 0, 1, 1, 100000), limit=-1)
.
.
.
```

and so on... until the current datetime;

I tried to iterate through it but I did not succeed.

Can you please help me?

Comment: "I tried to iterate through it but I did not succeed." i don't see anything related to your try.

Answer (score 0):

If you use panda's date_range as follows and collect all the dataframes in a list, I believe you will have what you need :)

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=pd.Timestamp("now"), periods=40)
```

It gives you an iterable of dates and you can adjust the periods or use freq if you want them to be separated by a certain interval